# Video capture in Direct show samples (AMCap)

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

I am using Direct show samples (AMCap) to capture live video streams. Video seems to be perfect but it does not capture audio within it.
I am not able to find out the reason. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?
Thank You.

Comment: Can you check if there is really no audio, or whether the audio is just silence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier SDKs, e.g. [Microsoft® DirectX® 9.0 SDK Update (October 2004)](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19320), contained more samples including audio capture, e.g.:

\DirectShow\Samples\C++\DirectShow\Capture\AudioCap

> **AudioCap** 
>   NOTE: In order to write .WAV files to your disk, you must first build and register the WavDest filter in the
>   Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\Filters\WAVDest directory.  Without this
>   filter, you may audition audio input, but you will not be able to
>   write it to your disk.